# Prove the composition of two reflections separated by $\frac{\pi}{n}$ is equivalent to a rotation by $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$

Tags: geometry

I am developing a proof but I'm not sure how to finish it. What I have so far looks like a kite. As you all know from group theory a rotation is the composition of two reflections. I am trying to prove the more specific proposition relating the angles of the reflections and the final angle of the rotation. If you see below, I am basically trying to show that $A + B = \frac{\pi}{n}$, hence proving that total rotation between point $P$ and its final destination $P_{a\circ b}$ is $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. Its been a long time since high school geometry so I'm not sure how to proceed. My intuition is if I could show that the inner triangle $\triangle O \sigma_A \sigma_B$ is isosceles, then maybe I can relate the angles $A$ and $B$ using SOH-CAH-TOA. However, the lines are not parallel, so I cannot use the old transverse theorems. Could you show me a few ways to proceed? Perhaps my memory is simply very foggy and I am overcomplicating. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\triangle O \sigma_A \sigma_B$ is not isosceles. What is isosceles is the triangle $P_{a\circ b} O P_a$ as well as the triangle $P_{0} O P_a$ (do you see why?). Hence $\angle P_{a\circ b} O P_0 = \angle P_{a\circ b} O P_a + \angle P_{0} O P_a = 2\angle P_{a\circ b} O \sigma_B + 2\angle P_0 O \sigma_A = 2(\angle P_{a} O \sigma_B + \angle P_a O \sigma_A) = 2 \angle \sigma_B O \sigma_A.$

Comment: No, I don't see why. Could you explain with reference to some theorems? Would be super useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sqrtpapi2001 A triangle is isosceles iff its altitude and its median coincide.

Answer (score 1):

I will present a slightly different approach. Firstly, wlog the first reflection is the standard reflection about the $x$ axis. We will mark said reflection with $\epsilon$. Mark a rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{2n}$ by $\rho$. This will mean the second reflection is of the form $\rho \epsilon \rho^{-1}$.
We know that:

$$\langle \epsilon, \rho\rangle = D_{2n}$$

The dihedral with $4n$ elements. This is also the group of symmetries on a $2n$-agon. It is known that all elements in said group are of one of the two forms:

$$ \rho^k, \epsilon \rho^k $$

So let's calculate $\rho \epsilon \rho^{-1} \epsilon$. This is a symmetry on a $2n$-agon or equivalently of the $2n$ roots of unity thus it's enough to find how it permutes them. Let's look at the action on $1$ and we get:

$$\rho \epsilon \rho^{-1} \epsilon(1) = \rho \epsilon(e^{-i \pi/n})=\rho(e^{i \pi/n}) = e^{2i \pi/n}$$

As fitting to a rotation by $2\pi / n$. Is there any other element in $D_{2n}$ that behaves this way? Well obviously every other rotation will send $1$ to a different value. Now:

$$\epsilon \rho^k (1) = e^{-ik \pi / n} = e^{(2n - k)\pi / n} $$

Meaning $\epsilon \rho^{2n - 2} $ Is another candidate. Let's check another point to distinguish the two. Let's take $e^{i\pi / n} $ then:

$$\rho \epsilon \rho^{-1} \epsilon(e^{i\pi / n}) = \rho \epsilon(e^{- 2 i \pi/n})=\rho(e^{2i \pi/n}) = e^{3 i \pi/n}$$

But:

$$\epsilon \rho^{-2} (e^{i\pi / n}) =  e^{i\pi / n} $$

Which means the only possible option for the composition is $\rho^2$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let the angle from the first line of reflection to the second line of reflection be $\theta$ (that is, $\frac{\pi}{n}$ in your diagram, but it could be any angle).

Then a point $P$ on the first line of reflection stays fixed for the first reflection. For the second reflection That point goes from being on an angle $\theta$ behind the second line of reflection to being on an angle $\theta$ ahead of the second line of reflection. So $P$ ends up $2\theta$ ahead of where it started. But a rotation is determined by what happens to any non-origin point. Since $P$ rotated by $2\theta$, the entire rotation is $2\theta$.